# How to block LinearLayout width?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to get a custom ListView with the next appearance:
[image]

The XML file is the next one:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tveva"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Nombre"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="2">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvpor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Porcentaje"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="2">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvnot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Nota"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My problems comes when I run the app and *tvnot* (TextView where you can see "Nota") is 4.5, for example, or 6.7 (They are marks with decimal) the ListView is perfectly aligned and has a good appearance, but if the mark is like 5.75 (Two decimal), the LinearLayout of the left (Which includes the TextView with "Porcentaje") moves a little to the left and the ListView losses its linearity:

[image]

I set the layout_weight attribute to each LinearLayout of the three TextViews. I'm not so expert on Android and I thought that just setting this attribute it would be fixed, but obviously I was wrong.

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use layout weights, you have to set the width (or height) to `0dp`, else the views may not be scaled properly. For example :

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4">
```

Comment: Yees! It works like I was looking for. I can't check this answer so soon(4 min remaining). Thank you @Dalmas

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to wrap all your elements within another LinearLayout. That's actually a terrible thing to do in Android. I suggest you to do this instead:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tveva"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Nombre"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:layout_weight=".4"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvpor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Porcentaje"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:layout_weight=".3"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvnot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Nota"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:layout_weight=".3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:weightSum="8" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tveva"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nombre"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvpor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Porcentaje"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvnot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nota"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but Damas has answer me before. I'm sorry

Answer (score -1):

generally when we use layout_weight than we use width or height as 0dp , according to situation , in your scenario 
u are using layout_width : wrap_content 
use layout_width : 0dp

Comment: ohh... thank u for reminding me this is comment , just because of this is a comment, u downward this ........  @MartinCazares